# I keep getting Bad Request Error from Telegram Api

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, request, py-telegram-bot-api

I really don't get why I have not been able to send inline links through telegram API, any solution?
I have previously tried using html inline link format but it's always giving me bad request. What part in my code am I missing it?

Link example: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/4958086

Error code: Bad Request: can't parse inline keyboard Markup Json object

```
NEWS_URL = "https://www.iflscience.com/latest"
TELEGRAM_API_URL = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{TELEGRAM_TOKEN}/"


def scrape_science_news():
    response = requests.get(url=NEWS_URL, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

        news_items = []

        card_list = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "card list-card"})

        for card in card_list[:3]:
            card_tbn = card.find("div", attrs={"class": "card-thumbnail"})
            card_img = card_tbn.picture.source.next_element.attrs["srcset"]

            card_content_h = card.find("div",
                                       attrs={"class": "card-content--header"})
            card_header = card_content_h.a.span.string

            card_content_b = card.find("div",
                                       attrs={"class": "card-content--body"})
            card_title = card_content_b.a.h3.string

            card_link_h = card_content_b.a.attrs["href"]
  
            news_items.append({
                "card_img": card_img,
                "card_header": card_header,
                "card_title": card_title,
                "card_link": card_link_h
            })

        return news_items

def send_news_to_telegram(news_items):
    inline_keyboard = []
    for item in news_items:
        img_ = item["card_img"]
        header_ = item["card_header"]
        title_ = item["card_title"]
        link_ = item["card_link"]
        print(link_)
        
        inline_keyboard.append([{
        "text": title_,
        "url": "link_"
        }])

        inline_keyboard_markup = {
            "inline_keyboard": inline_keyboard
        }

        # Prepare the message payload
        message = f"{header_}\n\n"
                try:
                    # Prepare the news payload
                    news = {
                        "photo": img_,
                        "caption": message,
                        "parse_mode": "MarkdownV2",
                        "reply_markup": inline_keyboard_markup,
                        "disable_web_page_preview": True,
                        "chat_id": CHAT_ID
                    }

                    # Send the image message
                    response = requests.post(TELEGRAM_API_URL + "sendPhoto",
                                             data=news)

                    # Check the response status
                    if response.status_code == 200:
                        # Save the title
                        with open("islog.txt", 'a') as file:
                            file.write(f"{title_}\n")
                    else:
                        print(response.text)

                except UnicodeError:
                    pass

# Main function to run the bot
def main():
    # Scrape the news from BBC News
    news_items = scrape_science_news()

    # Send the news to Telegram
    send_news_to_telegram(news_items)
main()
```

Comment: This site (`https://www.science.com/latest` ) can’t be reached. Can you share the correct news URL?

Comment: https://www.iflscience.com/latest